# Nested Attributes Child model don't save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I'm having a problem in the model saving with *nested attributes*. 
In the app, there's a *Customer*, that have 1..n *Contacts* witch in turn have 1..n *Telephones*.

I've searched a lot before asking here, and decided to make it save only the *Contact* first. Well, at first the *Customer* is stored, but *Contact* is not. From what I read there's no need to repeat the *... contacts.build* from *new* function in the *create*, and that the line ***"@customer = Customer.new(customer_params)"*** would create and store them both.

Why it's not working? (That's the first question.)

After some modifications and debugging, I found that when I set a second line building Contact (***...contacts.build(customer_params[:contacts_attributes])***) it's not saved because of an error of 'unknown attribute'. That's because between the hash :contacts_attribute and the content of it, it's added another hash, called ':0' (?). The structure of the hash that comes from the form is this :

***":contacts_attribute[:0[:name, :department, :email]]"***

I imagine that this hash :0 is for adding more than one *Contact* instance, that will come in hashes :1, :2 etc.

There's a way to store the *Contact* instance by getting this :0 hash? (How do I access this hash? Is it ***"... :contacts_attribute[0]"***?)

Below is the relevant code.
Thanks for the attention!

***customer.rb***

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
...    
has_many :contacts
accepts_nested_attributes_for :contacts, reject_if: lambda {|attributes| attributes['kind'].blank?}
... 
def change_by(user_id)
  update_attributes(changed_by: user_id, deleted_at: Time.now, updated_at: Time.now)
end

def delete(user_id)
  update_attributes(status: false, changed_by: user_id, deleted_at: Time.now, updated_at: Time.now)
end

private
...
end
```

***customers_controller.rb***

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController 

def new
  @customer = Customer.new
  @customer.contacts.new
end

def create
  user_id = session[:user_id]
  @customer = Customer.new(customer_params)
  if @customer.save
    @customer.change_by(user_id)
    flash[:success] = "Cliente cadastrado com sucesso!"
    redirect_to customers_url
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

private

def customer_params
  params.require(:customer).permit(:razao_social, :nome, :CPF_CNPJ,
              :adress_id, :email_nota, :transporter_id, :observacao, 
              contacts_attributes: [:nome, :setor, :email])
end
```

***Form***

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <%= form_for @customer do |f| %>
    <%= f.label "Dados Básicos" %>
    <div class="well">      
    <%= f.label :razao_social, "Razão Social" %>
    <%= f.text_field :razao_social %>

    <%= f.label :nome, "Nome" %>
    <%= f.text_field :nome %>

    <%= f.label :CPF_CNPJ, "CPF/CNPJ" %>
    <%= f.text_field :CPF_CNPJ %>

    <%= f.label :email_nota, "Email para nota" %>
    <%= f.email_field :email_nota %>

    <%= f.label :observacao, "Observações" %>
    <%= f.text_area :observacao %>
    </div>

    <%= f.fields_for :contacts do |k| %>
      <%= k.label "Contato" %>
      <div class="well">   
        <%= k.label :nome, "Nome" %>
        <%= k.text_field :nome %>

        <%= k.label :setor, "Setor" %>
        <%= k.text_field :setor %>

        <%= k.label :email, "Email" %>
        <%= k.email_field :email %>

      </div>   
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit "Cadastrar Cliente", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
reject_if: lambda {|attributes| attributes['kind'].blank?}
```

No sign of `:kind` in your form or your `customer_params`

This might have something to do with it.

Other than that, if you need an add/remove relationship for contacts, check out the [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) gem. If you only need one, then build that into your fields for:

```
<%= f.fields_for :contacts, @customer.contacts.first || @customer.contacts.build do |k| %>
```

The form will then be specific to a single instance of contact.

> There's a way to store the Contact instance by getting this :0 hash?
>   (How do I access this hash? Is it "... :contacts_attribute[0]"?)

You don't need to access it, that's what the `accepts_nested_attributes` is for. The rest of your code looks ok so sort out the rejection issue at the top and come back if there are still problems, and post the log output - specifically the params hash for the request!

Comment: Hey, Matt! Thank you! 
That was the problem... It's working perfectly with the Customer+Contact, but I don't have any idea of how the Telephone is declared in the Customer.. It has an association *belongs_to* with Contact, not with the Customer. How do I save it with the other two?

Comment: @LeandroPonsMalheiros If it's nested under the contact, you do the exact same as you did for the contact, `fields_for :telephone` and `accepts_nested_attributes` for it in the contact model.

Comment: @LeandroPonsMalheiros If this has helped, please accept the answer to close the question.